# Applying processing extent in zonal statistics

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, zonal-statistics

I am using Zonal Statistics to calculate statistics of a raster (input value raster) within land cover types which is specified by another raster (input raster). Both the Input raster and Input value raster are global and the Zonal Statistics (as table) works fine in global scale. However, when I specify processing extent (so that I can do the calculation by regions) using latitude/longitude, The resulting table is empty. I used different lat/lon but still get empty table.

Could you help?

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem. Both of my rasters, although they had the same reference, were in projected coordinate system and when I entered the latitude and longitude in degrees, ArcGIS understood it as 'meters' and so the problem. I projected the rasters to a geographic coordinate system and there was no problem.